# Drawing commutative left triangle

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Here is the figure I want to draw:

[image]

I do not know exactly from which vertex should I start drawing. Could anyone show me how to draw this please?

Comment: You have to consider a square with top left corner empty, so no arrows pointing from/to there.

Comment: @Sigur Can you show me how can I do that please?

Comment: As a recommendation, [this commutative diagram generator](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/) can be very helpful both for not having to write code yourself as well as checking how you would go about writing it.

Comment: @tolUene thank you !

Comment: "I do not know exactly from which vertex should I start drawing" >> you can start drawing from any vertex, as same as the way you choose the origin when you solving analytic geometry problems: choose any that you think fit. However, to start drawing that commutative diagram, a search in this texSE site with keyword "commutative diagram" will list a lot of how-to involving questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[margin=3.1415692mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        & P \ar[dl, dashed, "\tilde{f}" ']
            \ar[d, "f"]     \\
A \ar[r,twoheadrightarrow,"g" ']    & B 
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[margin=3.1415692mm,varwidth]{standalone}% show only image
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        & P \ar[dl, dashed, "\tilde{f}" ']  \\
A \ar[r,twoheadrightarrow,"g" ']    & B \ar[u, "f" ']   
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: for MWE (Minimal Working Example) is used `standalone` document class because it show only image with small border and not complete page as it happens at other document classes. However, proposed solution work at all other document classes. If you like to see result at `article` document class, just uncomment first line of MWE and comment the second line (with inserting % at beginning of second line).

Comment: Should I remove document class {article} from my file to draw this?

Comment: +1 for "margin=3.1415692mm"

Comment: @Smart20 No, you can keep your article class.

Comment: but it is giving me error@Dr.ManuelKuehner

Comment: @Smart20 Replace the complete line "\documentclass[margin=3.1415692mm,varwidth]{standalone}"

Comment: If I want the arrow between P and B to point upward and to have 2 head how can I do that?

Comment: pi is 3.14159265.. just a little different =)  a great answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 5):

Here there are two (2) MWE using `xy` package with the same tips of the `tikz-cd` in function of your tastes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=2.3pc@C=2.7pc{
& P \ar[d]^f \ar@{-->}[dl]_{\tilde{f}}\\
A \ar@{>>}[r]_g & B
}

\xymatrix@R=2.3pc@C=2.7pc{
& P \ar[d]^f \ar@{.>}[dl]_{\tilde{f}}\\
A \ar@{>>}[r]_g & B
}
\end{document}
```

[image]